# XSLT Conditional within For-Each

Tags: xslt

How can I include an if statement in my loop conditional in XSLT?

I have 2 or 3 different scenarios that define the data I want to loop through.  For example, there may or may not be a product ID.  If there is, I want to only loop through records that contain that product ID, otherwise I want all records.  I was trying to do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="knowledgebaseLoop">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($productId) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage/child::* [@parentID = $parentId]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage/child::* [@parentID = $parentId]"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="knowledgebaseLoop">
      <xsl:if test="position() &gt; $recordsPerPage * number($pageNumber - 1) and position() &lt;= number($recordsPerPage * number($pageNumber - 1) + $recordsPerPage )">
        <div id="main_body_listing">
          <div class="listing_title2"><a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(current()/@id)}"><xsl:value-of select="current()/@nodeName"/></a></div>
          <xsl:value-of select="current()/summary"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But it's unable to parse the XSLT.  I know the 2 conditions are the same, I was going to rewrite one once I got it working.  Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:

Here is some sample XML:

```
<Knowledgebase id="1073" parentID="-1" level="1" writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1062" template="1083" sortOrder="5" createDate="2011-04-20T13:43:41" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Knowledgebase" urlName="knowledgebase" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Chris" path="-1,1073" isDoc=""><pageTitle>Knowledgebase</pageTitle><metaDescription>knowledgebase</metaDescription><metaKeywords>knowledgebase</metaKeywords><umbracoUrlName /><Article id="1074" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="1" createDate="2011-04-20T13:44:13" updateDate="2011-05-16T09:39:12" nodeName="What is the answer to this question?" urlName="what-is-the-answer-to-this-question" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Chris" path="-1,1073,1074" isDoc=""><title>Change 2 Test 2</title><summary>Change 2 Test 2</summary><description>

&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Change 2 Test 2&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
</description><relatedProducts>1071,1076</relatedProducts><pageTitle>asd</pageTitle><metaDescription>asd</metaDescription><metaKeywords>asd</metaKeywords><umbracoUrlName /></Article><Article id="1082" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc=""><title>test</title><summary>test 22</summary><description>
&lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;

</description><relatedProducts>1075</relatedProducts><pageTitle /><metaDescription></metaDescription><metaKeywords></metaKeywords><umbracoUrlName /></Article><Article id="1146" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="4" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="3" createDate="2011-05-13T15:36:14" updateDate="2011-05-13T15:37:21" nodeName="Question 3" urlName="question-3" writerName="Content Approver" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1146" isDoc=""><title>Test</title><summary></summary><description>
&lt;p&gt;Test&lt;/p&gt;
</description><relatedProducts /><pageTitle>Test</pageTitle><metaDescription>test</metaDescription><metaKeywords>test</metaKeywords><umbracoUrlName /></Article></Knowledgebase>
```

I always need the articles where the parent ID is 1073.  If and only if a product ID exists, I want the articles where the product ID is in the relatedProducts list.  Thanks again!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression solution. :)

Comment: >"But it's unable to parse the XSLT." - is there an error message? If so, it would make everyone's life easier if you told us the message.

Comment: Would it?  Ok then.  The message very creatively says "Unable to parse Knowledgebase.xslt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, there may or may not be a
>   product ID. If there is, I want to
>   only loop through records that contain
>   that product ID, otherwise I want all
>   records.
>
> I always need the articles where the
>   parent ID is 1073. If and only if a
>   product ID exists, I want the articles
>   where the product ID is in the
>   `relatedProducts` list.

**Use**:

```
  <xsl:variable name="vDesiredArticles" select=
   "/*/Article[@parentID='1073'
              or
               contains(concat(',',relatedProducts,','),
                        concat(',', $pProductId, ',')
                        )
               ]"/>
```

**Here is a complete and short example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pProductId" select="1077"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vDesiredArticles" select=
   "/*/Article[@parentID='1073'
              or
               contains(concat(',',relatedProducts,','),
                        concat(',', $pProductId, ',')
                        )
               ]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vDesiredArticles"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one in the Update, but made more interesting):

```
<Knowledgebase id="1073" parentID="-1" level="1" writerID="0"
creatorID="0" nodeType="1062" template="1083" sortOrder="5"
createDate="2011-04-20T13:43:41" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23"
nodeName="Knowledgebase" urlName="knowledgebase" writerName="Chris"
creatorName="Chris" path="-1,1073" isDoc="">
    <pageTitle>Knowledgebase</pageTitle>
    <metaDescription>knowledgebase</metaDescription>
    <metaKeywords>knowledgebase</metaKeywords>
    <umbracoUrlName />
    <Article id="1074" parentID="1073" level="2"
    writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1063" template="1084"
    sortOrder="1" createDate="2011-04-20T13:44:13"
    updateDate="2011-05-16T09:39:12"
    nodeName="What is the answer to this question?"
    urlName="what-is-the-answer-to-this-question" writerName="Chris"
    creatorName="Chris" path="-1,1073,1074" isDoc="">
        <title>Change 2 Test 2</title>
        <summary>Change 2 Test 2</summary>
        <description>  &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Change 2 Test 2&lt;br /&gt; &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; </description>
        <relatedProducts>1071,1076</relatedProducts>
        <pageTitle>asd</pageTitle>
        <metaDescription>asd</metaDescription>
        <metaKeywords>asd</metaKeywords>
        <umbracoUrlName />
    </Article>
    <Article id="1082" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc="">
        <title>test</title>
        <summary>test 22</summary>
        <description> &lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;  </description>
        <relatedProducts>1075</relatedProducts>
        <pageTitle />
        <metaDescription></metaDescription>
        <metaKeywords></metaKeywords>
        <umbracoUrlName />
    </Article>
    <Article id="1088" parentID="1077" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc="">
        <title>test</title>
        <summary>test 22</summary>
        <description> &lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;  </description>
        <relatedProducts>1075,1039,1077</relatedProducts>
        <pageTitle />
        <metaDescription></metaDescription>
        <metaKeywords></metaKeywords>
        <umbracoUrlName />
    </Article>
    <Article id="1089" parentID="1077" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc="">
        <title>test</title>
        <summary>test 22</summary>
        <description> &lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;  </description>
        <relatedProducts>1075,1039,1078</relatedProducts>
        <pageTitle />
        <metaDescription></metaDescription>
        <metaKeywords></metaKeywords>
        <umbracoUrlName />
    </Article>
    <Article id="1146" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="4" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="3" createDate="2011-05-13T15:36:14" updateDate="2011-05-13T15:37:21" nodeName="Question 3" urlName="question-3" writerName="Content Approver" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1146" isDoc="">
        <title>Test</title>
        <summary></summary>
        <description> &lt;p&gt;Test&lt;/p&gt; </description>
        <relatedProducts />
        <pageTitle>Test</pageTitle>
        <metaDescription>test</metaDescription>
        <metaKeywords>test</metaKeywords>
        <umbracoUrlName />
    </Article>
</Knowledgebase>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (only Articles with `parentID="1073"` or whose `relatedProducts` contains the`$pProductId` (1077)):

```
<Article id="1074" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="1" createDate="2011-04-20T13:44:13" updateDate="2011-05-16T09:39:12" nodeName="What is the answer to this question?" urlName="what-is-the-answer-to-this-question" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Chris" path="-1,1073,1074" isDoc="">
   <title>Change 2 Test 2</title>
   <summary>Change 2 Test 2</summary>
   <description>  &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Change 2 Test 2&lt;br /&gt; &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; </description>
   <relatedProducts>1071,1076</relatedProducts>
   <pageTitle>asd</pageTitle>
   <metaDescription>asd</metaDescription>
   <metaKeywords>asd</metaKeywords>
   <umbracoUrlName/>
</Article>
<Article id="1082" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc="">
   <title>test</title>
   <summary>test 22</summary>
   <description> &lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;  </description>
   <relatedProducts>1075</relatedProducts>
   <pageTitle/>
   <metaDescription/>
   <metaKeywords/>
   <umbracoUrlName/>
</Article>
<Article id="1088" parentID="1077" level="2" writerID="0" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="2" createDate="2011-05-04T09:59:31" updateDate="2011-05-11T14:34:23" nodeName="Question 2" urlName="question-2" writerName="Chris" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1082" isDoc="">
   <title>test</title>
   <summary>test 22</summary>
   <description> &lt;p&gt;tst&lt;/p&gt;  </description>
   <relatedProducts>1075,1039,1077</relatedProducts>
   <pageTitle/>
   <metaDescription/>
   <metaKeywords/>
   <umbracoUrlName/>
</Article>
<Article id="1146" parentID="1073" level="2" writerID="4" creatorID="3" nodeType="1063" template="1084" sortOrder="3" createDate="2011-05-13T15:36:14" updateDate="2011-05-13T15:37:21" nodeName="Question 3" urlName="question-3" writerName="Content Approver" creatorName="Content Writer" path="-1,1073,1146" isDoc="">
   <title>Test</title>
   <summary/>
   <description> &lt;p&gt;Test&lt;/p&gt; </description>
   <relatedProducts/>
   <pageTitle>Test</pageTitle>
   <metaDescription>test</metaDescription>
   <metaKeywords>test</metaKeywords>
   <umbracoUrlName/>
</Article>
```

Comment: Dimitre - this is my preferred method of solving this - I don't really want to have multiple templates because there could be several cases and the template is actually the same, just the results differ.  However, it's not parentId I need to check it's productId and the relatedProducts could be a list.  I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work: <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/child::* [@parentID = $parentId][contains(@relatedProducts, $productId) or not($productId)]">

Comment: @Dexter: I am confused then -- in your provided code you are using `$parentID` . Is this a mistake? You probably need to edit the question and clarify/correct this.

Comment: @Dimitre: No, that's correct, $parentID is one of the variables I am using.  $parentID will always exist.  I need to ALSO check for $productId IF it exists.  Does this make sense?  I'm sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: @Dexter: THen I don't understand the question. Could you, please, provide a sample XML document (as small as possible), and describe what the result must be -- best also provide the exact exprected result ?

Comment: @Dimitre just updated with an example, let me know if this helps.  Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: @Dexter: Thanks. I will look at this when I am back home from work -- 5hrs from now.

Comment: @Dexter: I finally found some free time and now my answer contains a complete and short, one-liner XPath expression solution to your Update.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `xsl:choose` (to get the else part with a `xsl:otherwise`) plus a template:

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test='@productId'>
   <xsl:apply-templates select='filter by product id' />
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:apply-templates select='all of them' />
 </xsl:otherwise>
```

And then define a template to process the node list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check in the foreach loop construct, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[@productId != '']">
```

The condtion in the []  after item in the select indicate that you only want items with that attribute matching the condition.  So something like this would match:
    < item productId="BR9ES" >

But this would not:
    < item >

Comment: What if Product ID doesn't exist and I don't want to include it in the comparison at all?  How do I check for both cases?

Comment: You could use a second loop like this:
    <xsl:for-each select="item[@productId = '']">

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to test if an element exists in my XML doc:

```
<xsl:if test="@productID[.!='']">       //if it is not empty
<xsl:value-of select="@productID"/>     
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: What if Product ID doesn't exist and I don't want to include it in the comparison at all?  How do I check for both cases?